# Numerically solving a non-standard Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman PDE

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I would like to solve numerically a PDE determined by a Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman equation with the following form:

$$ru \left(p_1,p_2,t,\Delta\right)=\lambda p_1\left[u \left(1,p_2,t,\Delta+1\right) - u \left(p_1,p_2,t,\Delta\right) - \left(1-p_1\right) u^\prime_1 \left(p_1,p_2,t,\Delta\right)\right] + \lambda p_2\left[u \left(p_1,1,t,\Delta-1\right) - u \left(p_1,p_2,t,\Delta\right) - \left(1-p_2\right) u^\prime_2 \left(p_1,p_2,t,\Delta\right)\right] + u_t^\prime \left(p_1,p_2,t,\Delta\right)$$

$p_1$ and $p_2$ take values in $[0,1]$, $t\in[0,T]$, and $\Delta\in \mathbb Z$.

$T$, $\lambda$ and $r$ are just known positive constants. I also have some fairly simple boundary conditions on $u(p_1,p_2,T,\Delta)$.

Does anyone have a suggestion for the appropriate algorithm to use here? I am tempted to try Crank-Nicolson, but I know next to nothing about numerical solutions of PDEs, so I don't know if that'll work.